# Group by a column of comma delimited strings, but grouping should ignore specific order of strings

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data

```
> summary_table[, c('condition_list', 'condition_count')]
# A tibble: 4,306 x 2
   condition_list             condition_count
   <chr>                                <int>
 1 true control,control email               2
 2 true control,control email               1
 3 treatment, control email                 1
 4 true control, control email              1
 5 control email, true control              1
 6 control email                            1
 7 control email, treatment                 1
 8 control email,true control               2
 9 treatment                                1
10 control email, true control              1
```

Notice that  the column "condition_list" consists of comma-limited strings indicating an assignment to some condition, but some of these assignments are isomorphic to each other.  I'd like to get a tally of the number of rows in each condition like so:

```
summary_table %>% group_by(condition_list) %>%
  summarize(n= n())
```

However, this will treat each specific combination of `condition_list` as a separate group.  I want it to treat "control email, true control" the same as "true control, control email."  What is the best way to do this?

```
> dput(dputter)
structure(list(condition_list = c("true control,control email", 
"true control", "treatment", "true control", "control email", 
"control email", "control email", "control email,true control", 
"treatment", "control email", "true control,treatment", "treatment,true control", 
"treatment,true control,control email", "control email", "treatment", 
"true control,control email", "control email", "treatment", "true control,treatment", 
"control email", "control email,true control", "treatment", "control email", 
"control email", "control email,true control", "control email", 
"control email", "true control", "treatment", "true control", 
"treatment", "true control", "true control", "control email", 
"true control", "control email", "control email", "true control", 
"treatment", "treatment,true control,control email", "true control", 
"true control", "treatment,control email", "true control", "true control", 
"control email", "control email", "treatment", "control email", 
"true control"), condition_count = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

Comment: Can you include a `dput()` version of your data?

Comment: In the past, I've done this by first splitting the comma delimited list into separate columns, and then reconstructing the `condition_list` column by sorting the two strings before re-concatenating together.

Comment: Once you've done that, order is consistent, so you can use it as a grouping variable.

Comment: I added `dput`. Currently trying to figure out how to separate columns as per @Mako212's idea.  I'm using `separate` in dplyr with sep set to ",", but there will be a variable amount of columns depending on the size of the string, so it's not straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

summary_table %>% 
  mutate(condition_list = 
           strsplit(condition_list, ",") %>% 
           map(sort) %>% 
           map_chr(paste, collapse = ",")
         ) %>%
  group_by(condition_list) %>% 
  tally()
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  condition_list                           n
#  <chr>                                <int>
#1 control email                           17
#2 control email,treatment                  1
#3 control email,treatment,true control     2
#4 control email,true control               5
#5 treatment                                9
#6 treatment,true control                   3
#7 true control                            13
```

Comment: Oh this is cool.  I've never seen `map` used like that within a `mutate` call.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
dputter %>%
    mutate(condition_list = str_split(condition_list, ",")) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    group_by(condition_list) %>%
    tally()
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  condition_list     n
#  <chr>          <int>
#1 control email     25
#2 treatment         15
#3 true control      23
```

Explanation: Instead of `separate` we can use `str_split` (or in base R `strsplit`) to split entries on `","` producing a `list` column which we then `unnest` before summarising.

Comment: The intended output was actually the one produced by DiceboyT, but this is also very helpful for different reasons.  Thanks for taking the time -- very elegant.

Comment: I see @Parseltongue; yeah I wasn't 100% sure on the expected output;-) glad it all worked out.